# denormalizing in firebase functions - copy data from other docs on create

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to figure out how to create a merged/denormalized document for an order document in firebase, as described in the "Five Uses for Cloud Functions" Firebase video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=77XmRDtOL7c)

User creates the basic document, functions pulls in data from several other documents to create the desired result.

Here's a basic example of what I'd like to accomplish.

```
exports.orderCreate = functions.firestore
  .document('orders/{docId}').onCreate((snap, context) => {
    const id = context.params.docId;
    const orderDoc = snap.data();
    const branchId = orderDoc.branchId;
    const branchDoc = admin.firestore().collection('branches').doc(branchId);
    const bn = branchDoc.brandName;
    const ln = branchDoc.locationName;
    const logo = branchDoc.imageURL;    
    return admin.firestore().collection('orders')
      .doc(id).set({
        branchBrandName: bn,
        branchLocationName: ln,
        branchLogo: logo
      }, { merge: true });
});
```

Which way do I wave my hands to make this work?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `admin.firestore().collection('branches').doc(branchId);` you actually declare a [`DocumentReference`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/DocumentReference.html). Then, in order to get the values of the document fields, you need to call the **asynchronous** [`get()`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/DocumentReference.html#get) method.

So the following should do the trick:

```
exports.orderCreate = functions.firestore
    .document('orders/{docId}').onCreate((snap, context) => {
        const id = context.params.docId;
        const orderDoc = snap.data();
        const branchId = orderDoc.branchId;
        const branchDoc = admin.firestore().collection('branches').doc(branchId);

        return branchDoc.get()
            .then(branchDocSnapshot => {
                const bn = branchDocSnapshot.data().brandName;
                const ln = branchDocSnapshot.data().locationName;
                const logo = branchDocSnapshot.data().imageURL;
                return admin.firestore().collection('orders')
                    .doc(id).set({
                        branchBrandName: bn,
                        branchLocationName: ln,
                        branchLogo: logo
                    }, { merge: true });
            });

    });
```

---

You may need to deal with the case the doc does not exists, depending on your data model and app functions. See [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document) in the doc.

Comment: Appreciate this detailed answer.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Note for the future - you need to get the data() of the DocumentSnapshot - so for example const bn =  branchDocSnapshot.data().brandName

Comment: @BillyParadise Yes, you are right, my mistake! :-) Note that you could also do `const bn = branchDocSnapshot.get("brandName")`.